# Check if a TStringList contains specific symbols?

Tags: delphi

How can I check if a TStringList contains specific symbols?

I want to display a message if any of the following are found in the String List:

**\ / : * ? " < > |**

Something like:

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to SL.Count -1 do
    begin
      if SL.Strings[i] ?? then
      begin
        MessageDlg('Stringlist contains bad characters', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
      end else
      begin
        // no bad characters
      end;
    end;
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pos() function to test if a string contains a specific character. And, SL.Text is all the strings in one string.

```
if (Pos('\', SL.Text) > 0) OR (pos('/', SL.Text) > 0) then
  MessageDlg('Stringlist contains bad characters', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
```

etc.

Comment: It works great, but depending on the number of characters to check it could get pretty slow if only the last character checked occurs as Pos will have to iterate over all the text for all preceding characters that you want to check. @Martin James' answer will have better performance in that case as it iterates over Text only once.

Answer (score 2):

Use the pos() function to search for each of the symbols in the TStringList.Text property.  Alternatively, interate the characters in the TStringList.Text property and check if they are in the set of bad characters.  The second method is probably faster:

```
Function Tsomething.CheckList(list:TStringList;badChars:set of char):boolean;
var charIndex:integer;
    thisChar:char;
begin
  result:=false; // in case of empty list
  for charIndex:=1 to length(list.text) do // indices into a string start at 1
  begin
    thisChar:=list.text[charIndex];
    result:=thisChar in badChars;
    if result then exit;
  end;
end;
..
  if CheckList(myList,['\','/',':','*','?','"','<','>','|']) then application.messageBox(blah);
```

..but you would have to try both to be sure.

Comment: I should give myself -1 for a function that does not work :)  String property indexes start at 1, not 0, so the loop should run from 1 to length(list.text).  My bad, though this error would be quickly found.

Comment: lol. I didn't spot it either... But, why didn't you edit your answer yet? Anyway, I have done so for you. So you won't get any support e-mails... :-)

Comment: @MarjanVenema thanks for the edit - I have plenty enough support emails on my 'real' jobs already this morning :((  It's a bit annnoying that iterating over almost everything except strings needs '0..count-1'.

Answer (score 1):

```
const
  ForbiddenChars = ['\','/',':','*','?','"','<','>','|'];
var
  SL: TStringList;
  StrTemp: String;
  i,j: Integer;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
    begin
      StrTemp := SL.Strings[i];
      for j := 1 to Length(StrTemp) do
      begin
        if StrTemp[j] in ForbiddenChars then
        begin
          MessageDlg('Stringlist contains bad characters', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or you can use the simpler `StrUtils.PosSet(ForbiddenChars,SL.Strings[i])` if you use Free Pascal, but I don't know whether this function also exists in Delphi.

Comment: I think I will look at the PosSet function thanks, could be a tidier way of finding the bad characters from a set. EDIT: never mind I noticed you said FreePascal, I can't find PosSet in Delphi StrUtils. Roberts answer works perfect anyway :)